# How does one convert Pyspark Array Type of json Schema to String Type?

Tags: pyspark

Given the following Pystack array type of json schema, it is requested to convert it to string type, as contained in the following:

```
    jsonData = '{"data" : [{"number":1,"word": "One"}]}' 

    df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(values=jsonData)])

    schema = StructType([
        StructField("data", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField('number', IntegerType()),
            StructField('word', StringType())
        ])))
    ])

    df.withColumn('datavals', from_json(col('values'), schema)) \
        .selectExpr("datavals.data.number as number","datavals.data.word as word") \
        .show(truncate=False)

    df.printSchema()
```

I have above json format and dataframe schema

Getting output:

```
+------+-----+
|number|word |
+------+-----+ 
|\[1\]   |\[One\]| 
+------+-----+
```

Required output:

```
+------+-----+
|number|word | 
+------+-----+ 
|1     |One  | 
+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
df.withColumn('datavals', explode(from_json(col('values'), schema)['data'])) \
    .selectExpr("datavals.number as number","datavals.word as word") \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, Try below code.

```
SELECT
    INLINE(
        FROM_JSON(
            values,
            'data array<struct<number:int, word: string>>'
        ).data
    )
FROM VALUES ('{"data" : [{"number":1,"word": "One"}]}')  AS (values)
```

```
+------+----+
|number|word|
+------+----+
|1     |One |
+------+----+
```